# How to get downloadUrl after uploadString in firebase v9?

Tags: firebase

There is no documentation on firebase docs as to how to get UploadTask after uploadString is done in firebase v9.

```
const message4 = 'data:text/plain;base64,5b6p5Y+344GX44G+44GX44Gf77yB44GK44KB44Gn44Go44GG77yB';
uploadString(storageRef, message4, 'data_url').then((snapshot) => {
  console.log('Uploaded a data_url string!');
});
```

or how can I get the downloadUrl after the uploadString is completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer.

```
uploadString(storageRef, uri, 'data_url').then((snapshot) => {
    getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then(async (url) => {
            // Url  
    })
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).